# Toolbar : overflow menu button always showing

Tags: android, android-support-library, android-toolbar

[image]

**Problem**: after updating the support library and using Toolbars, the overflow menu button is always showing on devices with and without hardware menu button

**What I Need**: I want the overflow menu button to show only when the device has no hardware menu button

menu.xml

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto" >

<item
    android:id="@+id/action_settings"
    app:showAsAction="never"
    android:title="@string/action_settings"/>

<item
    android:id="@+id/import_data"
    app:showAsAction="never"
    android:title="@string/import_data"/>
```

in the activity (ActionBarActivity)

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}
```

and in onCreate : setSupportActionBar(mToolbar);

Help would be appreciated!

Comment: try app:showAsAction="always"

Comment: i don't want my actions to show always

Comment: This is intended behavior after and including `KITKAT`. [See here.](http://www.androidbeat.com/2013/12/google-kills-hardware-menu-button-android-4-4-kitkat/) It was made so the manufacturers drop now obsolete hardware menu key. In other words: Don't fix it, it's not broken.

Comment: return false; onCreateOptionsMenu, see if that helps

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the solution to my problem:

1- don't call `setSupportActionBar(mToolbar);` any more, instead use Toolbar directly

2- check if device has a hardware menu button by calling
`ViewConfigurationCompat.hasPermanentMenuKey(ViewConfiguration.get(getApplicationContext()));` :

3- if device has menu button i return true on in `onCreateOptionsMenu`, 
else i inflate the menu in the Toolbar

Answer (score 2):

You can change the behavior of the hardware menu button when it is present to show/hide the toolbar overflow menu. To do so, override the `onKeyUp` method of `Activity`.

```
@Override
public boolean onKeyUp(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_MENU) {
        if (mToolbar.isOverflowMenuShowing()) {
            mToolbar.hideOverflowMenu();
        } else {
            mToolbar.showOverflowMenu();
        }
        return true;
    }
    return super.onKeyUp(keyCode, event);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**It works fine (at least for me).**

In the onCreate method of your activity do:

```
    boolean hasHarwareMenu = ViewConfigurationCompat.hasPermanentMenuKey(ViewConfiguration.get(getApplicationContext()));
    if (!hasHarwareMenu) setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
```

And inflate your menu.xml as normal in the onCreateOptionsMenu.